# Java SE CDI maven dependencies?

Tags: java, cdi, maven-dependency

Java SE CDI maven dependencies?

```
public class FooProcessor {

    private FooService fooService;

    @Inject
    public FooProcessor(FooService fooService) {
        this.fooService = fooService;
    }
}
```

What are the jar dependencies for CDI for Java SE?

Which jar dependency has @Inject? Tried

```
compile "org.jboss.weld.se:weld-se-core:3.0.2.Final"
compile 'org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl:deltaspike-cdictrl-api'
compile group: 'javax.enterprise', name: 'cdi-api', version: '2.0.SP1'
compile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '7.0'
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you try in search engines? And the javaee-api should have it, so most likely you have other problems.

Comment: 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1' is required to resolve @Inject. If it is removed, compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure CDI in standalone mode by using `Weld` reference implementation.

Example:

```java
Weld weld = new Weld();
WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
FooProcessor fooProcessor = container.instance().select(FooProcessor.class).get();
weld.shutdown();
```

and weld dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Regarding `@Inject` it coming from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

and this coming from `JSR 330: Dependency Injection For Java` that introduces a standard set of annotations that can be used for dependency injection.

Comment: Did you notice that effectively OP has both these configured?  Weld in an older version though and the `@Inject` in the broader javaee-api...

Comment: but javaee-api does not have @Inject.

Comment: gradle build added: compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1', but it does not contain @Inject.

Comment: Added this ? ```compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'```

Comment: @Sunnyday: Please prove me wrong. The [javaee-api pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/javaee-api/7.0/javaee-api-7.0.pom) has the javaee-web-api (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/javaee-web-api/7.0/javaee-web-api-7.0.pom) which has exactly the `javax.inject` with both the group and artifact id and version 1. 100% identical to what you posted. But regardles of this, **why** would the complete javaee-api **NOT** contain `@Inject`? So both you as a commenter and the upvoter are wrong imo (or my build system has been broken for many years and automagically fixing things I did wrong)

Comment: And if even the explicit usage of `javax.inject` from this imo unhelpful answer (how well intended it might be, so no negative things here) does not work, you have a totally invisible problem (what is the package you imported for `@Inject`?)

Comment: Unhelpful? Depends... for cdi SE I said "weld" for @inject I said "java.inject" jar ... is it an answer to the question? Seems yes... remember the question : What are the jar dependencies for CDI for Java SE? –

Comment: Is there a standard way to create CDI container independent of  CDI implementations such as Weld?

Comment: What do mean by standard way? Depending on the application server you running  to you could have different implementation in action. Example in Apache Tomee the implementation is not weld but openwebbeans. Openwebbeans can be running in se mode too .```<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>openwebbeans-se</artifactId>
    ```

Comment: But OP already had the javaee-api as compile in its project, that contains `@Inject`... That is all I said.. So if that did not work, there is another prolem. If in your answer you'd explicitly stated that the javaee-api is to broad and the `javax.inject` is sufficient, that would be better, still if including the javaee-api bom (even if too broad) did not help. OP has a different problem. Which is confirmed by OP posting that adding `javax.inject` ALSO does not work...

Answer (score 0):

nowadays the annotation(s) mostly can come from 'javax.inject' and 'jakarta.inject' packages.

when starting sample within e.g. Weld 5.1.0 it is 'jakarta.inject', bundled into Weld itself

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se-shaded</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

also you NEED your class to be annotated with e.g. '@ApplicationScoped' - to be recognized by Weld as Weld-managed bean, and you NEED beans.xml
(can set only 'bean-discovery-mode' value and define no beans, btw):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" bean-discovery-mode="annotated"/>
```

... in /META-INF of your classpath for Weld to init successfully.

this is enough to make the sample take off. you can optionally add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
    <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

... for your Weld to start up (a little) faster.

p.s. and forget about `@Inject static Logger log` with Weld - even if strongly used in SE context, Weld(5.1.0) DOESN'T support it.